# change image in Xcode Swift when row selected

Tags: iphone, swift2

My first Phone app in Xcode (7.3 and Swift 2). Spent weeks trying to change an image when a row is selected.

myImageView is a custom cell class (swift file) with the imageView outlet:

---

```
import UIKit

class myTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var myCellLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

---

When a row is selected I want to replace the image but unable to reference the cell.myImageView.image{indexPath.row] = UIImage(named: “SquareGreen.png”)

This is OK

```
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! myTableViewCell
cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Square.png")
```

This does not work

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)  {

     myTableViewCell.myImageView.image[indexPath.row] = "SquareGreen.png"

     cell.myImageView.image[indexPath.row] = UIImage(named: "SquareGreen.png")

     // error               “use of unresolved identifier cell”
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: The error message seems fairly obvious...you don't have a variable named `cell` within the scope of your function.  (You can ask the table view for the index path of the current selection and for the cell at that index path.)

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
myTableViewCell.myImageView.image[indexPath.row] = "SquareGreen.png"
```

change to:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as myTableViewCell
cell.myImageView.image = "SquareGreen.png"
```

The first problem was what Phillip Mills pointed out in the comments - you don't have a cell variable, you need to create one. The second problem was that to assign a new image to the `myImageView` property, you need to assign as my code shows above (`image` is not an array or a dictionary).

Comment: Thanks for your advice, pasted your let cell trusting it would be OK. However, it throws error  " instance member "myImageView" cannot be used on type myTableviewCell"

Comment: I had a typo in my code, I fixed it now (changed `myTableViewCell.myImageView.image` to `cell.myImageView.image`).

Comment: Thanks paulvs it's fine now. My first post on this forum and got a result so I'm pleased. Appreciate your time and interest. jimL